# PHP PDO can't get MySQL to CREATE PROCEDURE and ALTER TABLE?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following file `schema.sql` to be used on a MySQL database:

```
--
-- schema.sql
--

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;



/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sometable` (`blah` tinyint(1) not null) Engine=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE call_procedure()

BEGIN

SET @column_exists = (SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = (SELECT DATABASE())
AND TABLE_NAME = 'sometable'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'stuff');

    -- Only modify if column exists
    IF @column_exists IS NULL THEN
    ALTER TABLE sometable ADD COLUMN stuff TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;
    END IF;

END;

//

DELIMITER ;

-- Execute the procedure
CALL call_procedure();

-- Drop the procedure
DROP PROCEDURE call_procedure;
```

When I go to my bash command line on Ubuntu, I can run this command and get exactly the results I want:

```
mysql -u root -pMyPass mydatabase < schema.sql
```

In other words, the table `sometable` is created and I see two columns `blah` and `stuff`.

So then I created a PHP script like this:

```
/// schema.php
$schema = file_get_contents('schema.sql');
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase","root","MyPass");
$PDO->exec("set names utf8");
$PDO->exec($schema);
```

When I run this script, I get a database table `sometable` that only has one column `blah`.  The column `stuff` never got created.

Why won't PHP run my sql script and create the column `stuff` the way my bash command line did it?

Comment: You need to execute one command at a time, not a pile of statements.

Comment: Check the MySQL error message. I'd bet on `DELIMITER //`. You might not need it with PHP/PDO.

Comment: In fact, you *cannot* use `DELIMITER` with PDO, because `DELIMITER` is not recognized by the SQL parser of the MySQL Server. It's a builtin command of the `mysql` client.